# What do I have to do and how much does it cost to get a device driver for Windows Vista / 7 (32 and 64 bit) signed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, 64-bit, driver-signing

I've got some drivers which are basically [LibUSB-Win32](http://libusb-win32.sourceforge.net/) with a new .inf file to describe product/vendor IDs and strings which describe my hardware. This works fine for 32 bit windows, but 64 bit versions have problems; namely that Microsoft in their wisdom require all drivers to be digitally signed.

So my questions are thus:

1. Is there a version of the LibUSB-Win32 drivers which are already signed I could use?
2. If there aren't already some signed ones I can canibalise, what exactly do I have to do to get my drivers signed.
3. Do I need to get 64 and 32 bit versions signed separately and will this cost more?
4. Is [this](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/install/authenticode.mspx) a free alternative to getting them signed?
5. Are there any other options I should consider besides requiring that my customers [boot into test mode](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/08/24/loading-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-7-and-vista-64-bit-x64/) each time they start their machines (not an option I'd consider).
6. Are there any other options for code signing apart from Verisign? Obviously a free/open source initiative like [OpenID](http://www.openid.co.uk/) would be awesome ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There are two separate issues at hand:

1. Signing the image file (i.e. the driver.sys file) to satisfy Kernel Mode Code Signing (KMCS)
2. Signing the driver package to satisfy driver installation (i.e. the driver.cat file).

If you take an existing driver signed by another entity (be it Microsoft's WinUSB or libusb-win32), that'll satisfy KMCS.

As to driver installation, you'd need your own Code Signing Certificate to sign a .cat file, which verifies that your .inf and the files it refers to (e.g. your .sys files) were not modified and truly come from you. It's somewhat less of a problem, since unlike KMCS (which stops your driver from loading), it won't prevent your driver from being installed but just present a warning to the user.

A Code Signing Certificate (**make sure it supports KMCS!**) will cost you hundreds of USD, depends on the CA you choose. Some might have plans which allow you to pay per signing event rather then globally per year. If you don't need to release many versions, this might be cheaper for you.

Comment: Starting in Windows 8, I think the INF files are required to be signed as well.  Prior to Windows 8, you were correct; it was possible to release unsigned drivers that use WinUSB or usbser.sys with just a warning that the publisher could not be verified.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, the INF file has to be signed on Windows 7 too, just not necessarily with an Authenticode certificate from a well-known CA. Did this policy change? Can you point me at any MSDN document or blog?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a MSDN document to point you to, but I have the experience of successfully delivering totally-unsigned drivers to thousands of customers who were using XP/Vista/7.  The existence of this dialog in Windows Vista/7 should also be pretty convincing to you:  http://a.pololu-files.com/picture/0J1348.600.png?717531f0f7c9a7c090f22a2939a61e70

Comment: Right, right. What kind of signature Windows 8 expects on the catalog file then?

Comment: See kmsigning.doc.  It has to be chained to a cert in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get away with trying the [libusb-winusb](http://libusb.org/wiki/windows_backend) version of libusb which tries to implement most of the existing functionality around the winusb driver (which is a signed MS binary so you don't need to do it yourself). However YMMV as winusb doesn't 100% map to all the functionality required in libusb.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this tutorial](http://www.killertechtips.com/2009/05/06/disable-driver-signing-in-windows-7-using-group-policy-editor/) that ignores unsigned drivers. I don't think that you want to pay because it costs something like $400 USD!

[Here is an other tutorial](http://www.killertechtips.com/2009/05/05/disable-driver-signing-windows-7/)

You can also run CMD as administrator and run the following:

```
bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Comment: I'd definitely shy away from requiring customers to boot into test mode or disable signing.  First, it'll put the "Test Mode" tag on their desktop which could be confusing.  Second, you're putting them in a position where unsigned and potentially untrusted kernel code could be loaded on their system.

Comment: Worth pointing out the `bcdedit.exe -set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS` doesn't work post Vista RTM.

Comment: it seems that bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON doens't work on win7 x64 also.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, it could cost as little as US$266 to have a device driver signed. My understanding is that only a company can get a driver signed. They won't do it for individuals.

Ref.: *[CERTUM Code Signing Certificates](http://www.certum.eu/certum/cert,offer_code_signing.xml)*

Answer (score 0):

I found a few ways to load a driver for free:

1. manual map the driver https://github.com/TheCruZ/kdmapper
2. disable driver signature enforcement- [info](https://pureinfotech.com/disable-driver-signature-enforcement-windows-10/#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20driver%20signature%20enforcement%20on%20Windows%2010%2C%20open%20Settings,Disable%20driver%20signature%20enforcement%E2%80%9D%20option.)

I personally use KD mapper